# Custom page splitter in pager for TableSorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am using the tablesorter to pagify some of my tables.

Is it possible (or in anyway easy to implement a way) for the pages to be by month or year?
E.g. instead of the regular pages < |1| 2 3 4 5 > to have < |01-2014| 02-2014 03-2014 >

Comment: Couldn't you pull them from the database and group the results by month? That would cut out a lot of your work.

Comment: Certainly i could. However, as the site is already is up and running, fetching the data and paging manually would be the less desired solution compared to if tablesorter had a relatively simple solution for that.

Comment: You'd just have to add one query to your class? `SELECT * FROM my_table GROUP BY MONTH(created)` or something of the like?

Comment: That (changing backend) is exactly what I would like to avoid. The best solution would in my opinion be if the plugin supported paging on a datatype instead of rows of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest solution would be to use the filter widget ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/3893/)):

HTML

```
<div class="pager">
    <a href="#" class="prev">&lt;</a> |
    <a href="#" data-column="1" data-filter="1/1/2014 - 2/1/2014 0:00 am">1-2014</a> |
    <a href="#" data-column="1" data-filter="2/1/2014 - 3/1/2014 0:00 am">2-2014</a> |
    <a href="#" data-column="1" data-filter="3/1/2014 - 4/1/2014 0:00 am">3-2014</a> |
    <a href="#" data-column="1" data-filter="4/1/2014 - 5/1/2014 0:00 am">4-2014</a> |
    <a href="#" data-column="1" data-filter="5/1/2014 - 6/1/2014 0:00 am">5-2014</a> |
    <a href="#" data-column="1" data-filter="6/1/2014 - 7/1/2014 0:00 am">6-2014</a> |
    <a href="#" data-column="1" data-filter="" class="active">all</a> |
    <a href="#" data-column="1" class="next">&gt;</a>
</div>
```

Script

```
var $table = $('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
    widgetOptions: {
        filter_columnFilters: false
    }
});

$('.pager').find('[data-filter]').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this).addClass('active'),
        query = [];
    $this.siblings().removeClass('active');
    // set selected filter
    query[ $this.data('column') ] = $this.data('filter');
    $.tablesorter.setFilters($table, query, true);
});

$('.next, .prev').on('click', function () {
    var $a = $('.pager').find('a[data-filter]'),
        current = $a.index($a.filter('.active')),
        // add/subtract one to get to next; -1 wraps to last
        next = current + ($(this).hasClass('next') ? 1 : -1);
    // wrap last back to first
    next = next >= $a.length ? 0 : next;
    $a.eq(next).click();
});
```